# Optimal algorithm to reduce time complexity for below search scenario?

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search

You are querying a 3rd party medical record system, they provide you two functions: 
1. Contain(SSN, index1, index2): This function will return true/false if the medical record of person with provided SSN sits in between index 1 and index 2

2. Get( index ): This function will return the medical record at that index.

Given an SSN, how do you query the system efficiently to get the medical record you need reducing time complexity?

The system is a collection of medical records that you can only access it through index, but the problem is that the only information you have from the patient is SSN. So you have to find out what is the index of the medical record of person with that SSN. How the 3rd party system implement the contain function is not your concern, it maybe fast or slow, regardless, you need to minimize the times you call this function.

My initial assumption when it was said there are 100 records was to use linear search algorithm with the index range like 1-10,10-20 but when its said there can be million records I was thinking of binary search by dividing it into half and proceeding likewise, example index between 1-500k etc,

what should be the best approach of this problem? I dont want the code just want to know if I was thinking in the right direction.

Comment: What if there are 2 million records, can there be any other optimized algorithm ?

Comment: Binary search is quite efficient. For 1 million records you need 20 tests. For 100 million records, you need 26 tests. For billion records (1000 millions), you need 30 tests. You could search every person's SSN in USA using 29 tests (US population being 300 millions).

Comment: Do you have sample values for index?

Comment: No i dont have any sample data, it was asked in an interview and this was the same I answered, But i think the interviewer wasnt satisfied. so wanted to ask if there is any better solution :)

Comment: Great thanks blackpen :)

Comment: If you gain more information about SSNs and Index values and the relation between them, you can *reuse* your searches. You can learn from your past searches, which you can reuse for future patients. I doubt if that may be the intension of the interviewer though.

Comment: I was kinda thinking about a radix tree. Especially with something like SSNs this would work great and at worst case you only did 9 checks to see if a SSN is there (if it finds subtrees for all but the last digit, but what are the odds).

Comment: Are the SSNs stored in some order?  If not, then binary search is out.  If so, then (a) binary search is the best you can do without using either the results of any previous searches or assumptions about the distribution of SSNs, and (b) there's no point having 2 separate query types since Contains(x, i, j) can be trivially implemented by calling Get(i) and Get(j) and seeing if x lies between their results.  (Only one of these calls is needed on the second and subsequent iterations of a binary search, since we already have the other endpoint.)